# Issue with Json parse when using multiple lines

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I was trying to create an array of objects is JSON form, and than parsing them back into an object. Below is a working example:

```
var personString = '{"name": "matt","age": 24,"faceFeatures":{"eyes": "green","nose": "medium"},
"hats":["Jays", "TO6", "BassPro"]}'

var person = JSON.parse(personString)
console.log(person)
```

This code works no problem. However, when I try to clean up my code and format it on multiple lines, my code fails, here is an example:

```
var personString = '{
    "name": "matt",
    "age": 24,
    "faceFeatures":{"eyes": "green","nose": "medium"},
    "hats":["Jays", "TO6", "BassPro"]
}'
```

I used the JSON validator, and it says this block of code is still valid however, my text editor, which is sublime, keeps giving me pink lines saying I have an enclosed string, which doesn't make sense to me. As it is the exact same code as above!

Of course I would prefer the second formatted version of this, as it is much cleaner to read and will be needed when I use an array of objects. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use ` not ' this is for multiline strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't create multiline string like this you need to add `\` or use template literal

```
var personString = `{
    "name": "matt",
    "age": 24,
    "faceFeatures":{"eyes": "green","nose": "medium"},
    "hats":["Jays", "TO6", "BassPro"]
}`
// OR
var personString = '{ \
    "name": "matt",   \
    "age": 24,        \
    "faceFeatures":{"eyes": "green","nose": "medium"}, \
    "hats":["Jays", "TO6", "BassPro"] \
}'
```